# Matplotlib: forcing plot function to interpolate line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I making this plot with custom bins, so some of them are empty. Eventually I want to remove the bars and keep only the line. But I need the line to simply start at the first point (rather than on the x axis) and connect with all the others. How do I prevent those vertical lines?

[image]

Comment: looks like you have NaNs in your data. Drop them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use the bin values for the y values and the bin edges/centers for the x values and just plot a line?

Comment: Use the bin values for the y values and the bin edges/centers for the x values and just plot a line? - `plt.plot(bin_centers,bin_values)`

Comment: Not exactly NaNs but there were points in which y axis was 0. So I removed those points from both axes and now it works. Thank you.